# Evaluating triple integral under linear transformation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, volume, multiple-integral

Given linear transformation: $$T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3, T(x,y,x)= (3y+4z, 2x-3z, x+3y) $$
We need to evaluate the triple integral :
$$\int \int \int_ {T(C)} (2x+y-2z) dx dy dz $$
where $C= \{{(x,y,z): 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1, 0 \le z\le 1}\}$

I understand that the unit cube gets transformed to a slanted parallelopiped, but how can I find the limits of integration in this case?

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)=2x+y-2z$. Then\begin{align}\iiint_{T(C)}2x-y-2z\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz&=\iiint_{T(C)}f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\\&=\iiint_Cf\bigl(T(x,y,z)\bigr)|\det T|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\\&=15\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^15z\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\\&=\frac{75}2.\end{align}

Comment: May be I am wrong, but question is about limits of integration for $T(C)$.

Comment: @zkutch That’s definitely not the right approach.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. I'm glad someone, especially you, is finally paying attention to this, but your sentence is not unambiguous. I can hear your opinion in private, if you prefer.

Comment: @zkutch I meant that the solution José gave is the preferred solution. Think about trying to integrate directly over a parallelogram in $\Bbb R^2$: Typically you will have to write this as a sum of three iterated integrals. A parallelepiped is more complicated yet. Your comment to the OP, I believe, is off base. How does what you said give the correct limits of integration?

Comment: I understand and accept your point if the main goal is to calculate the integral. But I am talking about the question about the boundaries of a new body. If your question is related to my comment, this is the first step.

Comment: @zkutch I disagree. That is not the right way to set up and think through iterated integrals — other than for rectangles aligned with the axes.